# Do I need to invoke JavaScript to construct a CTS query from JSON?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

In MarkLogic, is there a way to construct a CTS query from a JSON serialization thereof in XQuery (without having to invoke JavaScript)? I only see a JSON example using JavaScript (and XML using XQuery) but not a JSON example using XQuery here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/cts_query#id_17645

I successfully got the desired result when I ran the following code, but I would like to do this in just XQuery instead:

```
let $script := 'var json; cts.query(fn.head(xdmp.fromJsonString(json)))'
return
  xdmp:javascript-eval($script, map:entry("json", '{"wordQuery":{"text":["hello"], "options":["lang=en"]}}'))
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Do you mean "pure XQuery" or "MarkLogic XQuery"? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Touché! Pure MarkLogic XQuery ;-)

Comment: I removed (or reworded) both instances of "pure XQuery", as they are misleading. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter and easier method is to use [`xdmp:unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote)

```
xdmp:unquote('{"wordQuery":{"text":["hello"], "options":["lang=en"]}}')/object-node()  
  => cts:query()
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that. It also dodges those confusingly-named functions. Only difference is I'm still using the mapping operator: `$json-string ! xdmp:unquote(.)/object-node() ! cts:query(.)`

Answer (score 2):

- [`xdmp:from-json-string()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json-string) can be used to parse a JSON string. It will construct a JSON object (which is basically a specialized map).
- You can convert that JSON object into a JSON document using [`xdmp:to-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:to-json).
- select the child JSON `object-node()` from the returned document-object, and send to [`cts:query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:query) to parse it into a `cts:query`

Like this:

```
xdmp:from-json-string('{"wordQuery":{"text":["hello"], "options":["lang=en"]}}') 
  ! xdmp:to-json(.)/object-node() 
  ! cts:query(.)
```

Comment: Thanks Mads! That's doubly tricky. First the distinction between a JSON object and a JSON document. Then the need to grab the object-node() child of the document node. I had gotten so far as to use cts:query(xdmp:from-json-string($json)), but I was missing a couple more steps (that didn't apply in the JavaScript version). Thank you again! Works perfectly.

Comment: Agreed, it's sort of convoluted and the names of the functions aren't always clear what is being constructed and returned. It took me a while to figure it out myself!

Comment: Yes, I didn't even mention the confusing names.  Thanks for your kindness & understanding.